# How to load bootstrap css BEFORE my other css using bootstrap-sass gem ? ( Rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have such problem: I included bootstrap using

```
  @import "bootstrap";
```

in my footer.css.scss and my css is overrided by bootstrap. How can I preload bootstrap before all my files ?

I tried to delete this line, but it continues to override my css.

How can I load bootstrap css before my files ?

Comment: what exactly do you want to override and what not? you can override boostrap variables, that has to be done before loading bootstrap partials or you can override as usual in css in which case you might need to use !important in some places... more information please.

Comment: It's strange, because in one project it is easily overriding in application.css, and in other(with the same code, but I pulled it from GitHub) I should put everything in `.scss` file extension. Can you suggest why it is happening ? I want to load MINE files after bootstrap.

Comment: loading it after does not always mean it will have precedence. that's why I am asking for more information.

Comment: @markus-tharkun, I just want to override bootstrap with some CSS, maybe I should use other gem ?

Comment: @markus-tharkun, `bootstrap.css`